# Django apply migrate for inherit models

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a base model BaseStage  and two inherit models TestSpend , StageSpend

```
class BaseStage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField
    date = models.DateField
.......

class TestSpend(BaseStage):
    direction = models.CharField


class StageSpend(BaseStage):
    direction = models.CharField
```

Now Im try to add constraints field to Meta

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = ''
    verbose_name_plural = ''
    constraints = [
         models.UniqueConstraint(
             fields=['direction', 'name', 'date'], name='unique_name'
         )
     ]
```

to both models. Successfully running the `makemigrations` command, but when run `migarte` got

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "name" named in key does not exist
```

Comment: Has 'BaseStage' the setting `class Meta: abstract=True`? If not , you cannot use your models the way you are doing. Is `class Meta` you wrote in `TestSpeed` and `StageSpend` or in `BaseStage`?

Comment: I added `abstract=True`   to my base model and make successfull migration. Thank! If you want, you could write it as a answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class BaseStage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateField()
    # Other fields
    
    @property
    def direction(self):
        raise NotImplemented
   
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        constraints = [UniqueConstraint(name='%(class)s_unique_name', fields=['direction', 'name', 'date'])]

class TestSpend(BaseStage):
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class StageSpend(BaseStage):
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Replace the various `max_length` values with your needs. Note that right now the implementation of the `direction` field in the various subclasses is always the same, so you could use one unique model maybe with a choice field that describes the type of stage.